# Using ListNav with data attributes

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery plugin ListNav to display a list of my "Authors" alphabetically.

This works great for sorting the first names alphabetically, but I need it to sort by last name.

Is there a way to accomplish this using the ListNav plugin? perhaps one way is to store the last name in a data attribute (data-last-name="Smith") and then have the plugin use that data attribute to sort the lists?

(Plugin) http://www.ihwy.com/Labs/jquery-listnav-plugin.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my version of ListNav https://github.com/esteinborn/jquery-listnav.

You can assign a `filterSelector` option to filter by a selector:

Wrap your last name inside of a `<span class="lastname"></span>`

and then set the option `filterSelector: '.lastname'` and you should be all set.